Quote identification: Alles, was man lernen kann, lohnt sich nicht, gelernt zu werden
Long time ago, I don't know where but suspect in a Youtube video, I heard this German quote:

Alles, was man lernen kann, lohnt sich nicht, gelernt zu werden.

It might well be that this was a German transcript voice and that the original was actually in English. In English, the quote would be:

All that can be learned is not worth learning.

Unfortunately, I have no further information about the origin of the quote and an online search leads to nothing.
So, who said this and where?

It appears to be a variant of Oscar Wilde's "Education is an admirable thing, but it is well to remember from time to time that nothing that is worth knowing can be taught." (source, quote nr. 21) (Note also that German gelernt and gelehrt are pretty close and may be misremembered)

Context: ‘The Critic As Artist’ in Intentions (1891), p. 111.
